# Print commas between each item in a seq

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to print each item of a sequence separated by commas, without printing a trailing comma. I want to avoid using `clojure.string/join` because I don't want to create an intermediate string (that's what I was doing before and the code was much harder to follow). I'd rather just print the elements.

This is what I have right now:

```
(doseq [element a-map]
  (printf "%s = %s" (key element) (val element))
  (print ", "))
```

I can think of several ways to do this:

1. Print the first item outside the `doseq`, then print each item with a preceding comma.

   ```
   (printf "%s = %s" (key (first a-map)) (val (first a-map)))
   (doseq [element (rest a-map)]
     (print ", ")
     (printf "%s = %s" (key element) (val element)))
   ```
2. Print all items except the last followed by a comma, then print the last item outside the `doseq`. The code would be similar to the first option, but inefficient for seqs that aren't randomly accesible.
3. Use `interpose` and check whether `element` is a string or not.

   ```
   (doseq [element (interpose ", " a-map)]
     (if (str? element)
       (print element)
       (printf "%s = %s" (key element) (val element))))
   ```

I don't like 1 or 2, because of the duplication. I don't like 3 because of the if condition.

Comment: Why do you need to check if element is a string in #3 — what else do you expect it to be? BTW why do you need to `(print element)` in #3 at all?

Comment: Oh, looks like I have a few typos, where I used `a-map` instead of `element`. But to answer your question, I expect `element` to be either a string or a map element from `a-map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's a new try:

```
(defn str-commas [a-map]
  (doseq [[[k v] sep] (partition-all 2 (interpose ", " a-map))]
    (printf "%s = %s%s" k v (or sep ""))))
```

`partition` returns lists of size N, but since interposing commas does not create an even number of elements, the last key-value pair was dropped. `partition-all` may include partitions with less elements (the last element only contains the key-value pair).

The trick is to use the `(or sep "")` since we know that the last element will be lacking a separator, thus it will be null.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just equivalent to `(clojure.string/join ...)` and I am trying to avoid creating an intermediate string for the purposes of this code.

Comment: @Brigham - this version should work without intermediate strings